# How to search PFObject UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform

Im trying to figure out how to search/Query a PFObject and not a user. This is what I have to so far and its finding but not displaying. I found [this post](https://www.parse.com/questions/programmatic-search-capability-using-parse) and followed it but did not come to a running result because it does not show results. I cant figure out how to show the PFObject so thats what I need help with:)

```
-(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"by"];  //this is based on whatever query you are trying to accomplish
    [query whereKeyExists:@"title"]; //this is based on whatever query you are trying to accomplish
    [query whereKey:@"title" containsString:searchTerm];

    NSArray *results  = [query findObjects];

    NSLog(@"%@", results);
   // NSLog(@"%u", results.count);

    [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}
```

Then I am trying to display here:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
   PFTableViewCell *cell = (PFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];   


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[PFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:self.textKey];



    if (tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

      /*  PFObject *title = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"title"];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
        PFObject *searchedUser = [query getObjectWithId:title.objectId]; NSString * usernameString = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"title"]; cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", usernameString];
       */
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
        [query whereKey:@"title" equalTo:@"by"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d title", objects.count);
                // Do something with the found objects
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];


    }
    if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
        [query whereKey:@"title" equalTo:@"by"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // The find succeeded.
                NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d title", objects.count);
                // Do something with the found objects
                for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];

       /* //PFObject *obj2 = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
        PFObject *searchedUser = [query getObjectWithId:obj2.objectId];
        NSString *first = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *last = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"by"];
        cell.textLabel.text = [first substringToIndex:1];
        NSString *subscript = last;
       // cell.categoryName.text = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"category"];
        */
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: So.. what you get from the NSLogs? What do you want exactly. I'm working with parse and I don't have any problem.

Comment: Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug. @FabioCardoso

Answer (score 2):

What your code is doing is that first, in filterResults, you are retrieving all objects that contain the field "by" and the field "title" and where "title" contains searchTerm.

THEN, when you create a cell, you do another query (which you should never do, as it now has a long-lasting operation to do for each and every cell being displayed. Scrolling this view would never work. And besides; you are comparing the title with the string @"by", which I am pretty sure is not your intention.

So, your main problem is in they way you build your query, and your secondary problem is that you're doing this for every cell.

What you need to do is get all the data you want on the first search, and then iterate through those data in an array when displaying.

Something like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {        
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"TestClass"];
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
        query.limit = 50;
        [query whereKey:@"city" equalTo:chosenCity];
        [query whereKey:@"sex" equalTo:@"female"];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:)];

    - (void)callbackLoadObjectsFromParse:(NSArray *)result error:(NSError *)error {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully fetched %d entries", result.count);

            self.allTestObjects = result;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
```

Then, later in cellForRowAtIndexPath you use **this array** (no more queries) as the datasource for your data:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject * testObject = [self.allTestObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],
    cell.textLabel.text = [testObject objectForKey:@"name"];

    return cell;
    }
```

When working with databases, never do lookups in tableviewcells. Prepare your data first, and then present them with top performance.

Comment: Im still not getting anything.. Is allTestObjects an NSMutableArray?

Comment: No, allTestObjects is just an array, the one created by the "findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget" method. This background operation calls the "callbackLoadObjectsFromParse" method when it is done, and the query-result (all matching objects) are in that array. 

The "Warning: A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug." message you get, is the Parse API warning you that you are querying parse.com on the main thread rather than in a background thread.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error from allTestObjects. I tried using a NSArray but still no luck.I cant get it to display.